# Python/Django multipage form redirects

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I currently have the following views, both of which control forms.  Select campaign saves posted data to session variables, before moving onto the second view via a redirect.  The problem arises however that the get method of `AddMessage` is ignored and goes straight to the post method, the second half of the form however is output by the get method.

Anyone shed some light on the situation?

```
class SelectCampaign(View):
    template_name = "dash/SelectCampaign.html"

    form = messageForm1()


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        up = user.get_profile()
        self.form.fields['location'].queryset = up.owned_locations.all()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = messageForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['MMANAGER_FORM_CTYPE'] = form.cleaned_data['campaign_type']
            request.session['MMANAGER_FORM_LOCATION'] = form.cleaned_data['location']
            return redirect(reverse('add_message'))
        else:
            #say whats not valid and return it
            form = messageForm1(request.POST)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})



class AddMessage(View):

    template_name = "dash/AddMessage.html"
    form = messageForm2()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = messageForm2(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            campaign_type = request.session.get('MMANAGER_FORM_CTYPE')
            location = request.session.get('MMANAGER_FORM_LOCATION')
            ...
            return redirect(reverse('message_manager'))
        else:
            #say whats not valid and return it
            form = applicantsForm(request.POST)

            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: are you sure that you have properly set-up HTML `form` action attribute?

Comment: This is far too long ago for me to even remember what this was for let alone if I ever fixed it.